# I only get NETWORK_PROVIDER when requesting GPS_PROVIDER on Huawei P20?

Tags: xamarin.android, gps

My app uses Location Manager to get location updates. On Samsung etc. it works fine but not for all Huawei P20 users. With this code

```
locationMgr.RequestLocationUpdates (LocationManager.GpsProvider, 2000, 1, this);

...

public void OnLocationChanged(Android.Locations.Location location)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Location changed update: {0} provider, {1} accuracy", location.Provider, location.Accuracy);

   ...
```

...the OnLocationChanged method will in certain scenarios return "network" as provider even though I've specified "gps".

My test P20 device has the option to set "best location" in the device settings. If turned off, I get "gps" as provider with good accuracy but with the setting turned on I only get "network" with bad accuracy. Is this a bug in my code, xamarins implementation, android or Huaweis android implementation. Is there a way to force to only get "gps"?